# Does jdbc's DriverManager support multi-threaded logging

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, jdbc

I'm working with some existing and pretty old application code that handles DB connections through different drivers using DriverManager. It's a multi-threaded app where each connection is a thread(whether new or existing) and it sets a log writer to get/redirect connection error messages into app's log files. PrintWriter is implemented as an inner anonymous class under a class that handles interactions with a DB and other our components as well. This outer class is not a thread and gets instantiated when a new connection thread is created meaning, if my understanding is correct, both, outer and inner classes, are suppose to be accessible from "their" thread only.
However, when we set the DriverManager's logger, I noticed:
1. last set writer being "used" by all connections.
2. when I try to access some local vars in the outer class from a method in the Writer(flush() for example), all threads/connections work with the same(last set) logger's outer class which constitutes a race condition.
Does this mean that DriverManager's logging is not thread safe? Or, I should say, - may not be safe. Our logging seems to be working fine as the Writer we set is nor referencing a particular file but uses a static reference from the outer class to redirect to our logging facility. However, I have not seen any restriction that I cant do just that, - pass a writer to a certain file. Or, what happens if a thread would set logger to null upon completing, - all threads loose logging from the DriverManager or/and the driver being used?
I'd really appreciate if anyone could clarify this for me.
Thank you.

Comment: That entirely depends on your implementation.  If you have an old JDBC driver, you shouldn't be surprised if it has bugs in it.  I would check if the driver has been updated.

Comment: @Peter actually, it is the opposite, - our code is old(working though) but the driver is new. I first wanted to complain about the driver since my project is resulted from finding quite a few bugs in it but: 1. same behavior happens with other drivers and 2. DriverManager's implementation appears to explain it as logger is private static in it.

Comment: I think the fact that your code ever worked was a miracle, if indeed it ever did. The DriverManager PrintWriter get and set are both static so there is a clear implication and indeed clear statements in the Javadoc that the PrintWriter being set is used by the a DriverManager and all drivers. I can't see any basis for the old code's expectation that it is per-thread.

Comment: @EJP, thanks. no miracles, just a matter of finding the right solution. Saying that DriverManager doesn't support logging for multi-threaded apps, sounds unreal. I'd not necessary agree that saying logger is used by all drivers is equivalent to - "all connections will use the same logger". Indeed, we have all traces written down per thread correctly, including driver's output. Even the fact that DriverManager doesn't do connection pooling doesn't mean no multi-threading is supported, then what about logging?

Comment: @EJP, also, I'm not sure your statement that get-set methods being static is a "clear implication" is very accurate, - what if inside they work with a static collection of loggers not just with a static PW as in this case?

Comment: I didn't say it didn't support logging for multi-threaded apps. I said it was a static attribute which perforce can't support per-thread values. If you don't believe me see the Javadoc, and explain to me how a static attribute can support per-thread values. Your final question is pure speculation. What if they don't? And where is any if that stated in the Javadoc? Or the JDBC specification?

Comment: @EJP, You are right, I agree. After some researching I better understand now. The implementation I'm working with now, which is not mine, the guy's long gone and nobody else could really explain why it is done the way it is. I was experiencing threading issues for my feature and it was not clear what the cause was as logging works fine. Well, in the end - it's our old implementation, indeed. Having our PW implemented as an inner class of our connection class, being instantiated each time and set to DM is wrong. Thank you.